# Java: "java google translate text to speech"

Tags: java, google-translate

I am trying to develop an application with the **"java-google-translate-text-to-speech"**. So for that I saw the API and I execute the sample program.

```
Audio audio = Audio.getInstance();
InputStream sound = audio.getAudio("I am a bus", Language.ENGLISH);
audio.play(sound);
```

When I execute this code I was able to listen the content. But when I change the Language from ENGLISH to TELUGU I am getting an exception like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=I%20am%20a%20bus&tl=te
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1610)
at com.gtranslate.Audio.getAudio(Audio.java:34)
at speech.Play.main(Play.java:15)
```

And also I observed this behaviour for some other languages as well.

1. So how can I solve this issue...???
2. My second question is, I want to send an automatic email with this audio/content. So when ever the user opens that mail the audio needs to be played. Is it possible with this Google API...???

Can any one help me on these two issues...

Thanks & Regards,
Amar.

Comment: Well, if I type the address into the browser, I get a 404 error...

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm noting that your FileNotFound comes as the result of a request to translate.google.com, so I'm guessing that the library you're using is just wrapping calls to an API provided there.

Based on that, it looks to me like some languages just don't have TTS enabled yet - presumably Google hasn't created an audio database for them yet. For instance, go to "http://translate.google.com/#en/es/asdf", and note the "audio" icon in the spanish box on the left. Then select Telugu as the "to" language, and note that the audio icon vanishes. With some trial and error, I found that Marathi and Urdu, among others, are also missing audio.

So, unfortunately, I think there isn't a solution using this library, if you really want Telugu audio.

To your second question, I don't have a specific answer, although more detail would help - I know that it's difficult to do audio embedding in email, but depending on the infrastructure you have available/the scale of your operation, you might be able to host the files somewhere, and provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a limit of 100 characters . You will need to pass the text to be converted in chunks of less than 100 characters.

Comment: yes, I've also attempting this via the API, and at the time there was also a limit to the number of requests you could make before it would reject subsequent requests.  I can't comment if this is still in place now.  But attempts to automate its use failed rather rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages don't have audio translation so it is obvious that will return a null pointer exception. Go to http://translate.google.com/ and see what languages do have audio translation.